# How to fetch row values and delete data using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have a DataTable where I display all the values from the API. Now I have a Detail column, where I have the href tag with a delete button. I want to add a class name or id, but it throws an error. Here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/otLjqdx4/7/).

I want to fetch the row values and delete the data. Can you please help me with this?

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Message</th>
           <th>Details</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

Script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing" : true,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/un18a",
                dataSrc : ''
            },
            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : "name"
            }, {
                "data" : "email"
            }, {
                "data" : "subject"
            }, {
                "data" : "message"
            },
            {
                    "mData": "Details",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a id="delete" href='/Details/" + row.id + "'>Delete</a>";
                    }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try this [new one](https://jsfiddle.net/4ta87fmh/)

How about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2mcL4kba/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/un18a",
            dataSrc : ''
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "name"
        }, {
            "data" : "email"
        }, {
            "data" : "subject"
        }, {
            "data" : "message"
        },
        {
                "mData": "Details",
                "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                console.log(row)
                    return "<a class='delete' data-obj='" + JSON.stringify(row)
 + "' href='/Details/" + row.id + "'>Delete</a>";
                }
        }]
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let data = $(this).data("obj")
        alert("Name: " + data.name + " Email: " + data.email + " Subject: " + data.subject + " Message: " + data.message ) 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it is working, try this as i tried in your JSFiddle example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/un18a",
        dataSrc : ''
    },
    "columns" : [ {
        "data" : "name"
    }, {
        "data" : "email"
    }, {
        "data" : "subject"
    }, {
        "data" : "message"
    },
    {
            "mData": "Details",
            "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                return "<a id='rec1' class='thisclass' href='/Details/" + row.id + "'>Delete</a>";
            }
    }]
});
```

});

also add in css block

```
.thisclass{
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: thank you, can you tell me also how can i fetch the row values on click of the delete .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/un18a",
        dataSrc : ''
    },
    "columns" : [ {
        "data" : "name"
    }, {
        "data" : "email"
    }, {
        "data" : "subject"
    }, {
        "data" : "message"
    },
    {
            "mData": "Details",
            "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                return "<a href='https://api.myjson.com/bins/un18a/Details/" + row.id + "'>Delete</a>";
            }
    }]
});
```

});

Make a controller function for delete, the call that function when https://api.myjson.com/bins/un18a/Details/{id} route calls